# Structuring my web server in node

Tags: node.js, express

i am working on a web server which is currently being developed for web browsers not mobile apps.

But in future we may need to scale it for mobile apps also, so i want to be more careful while developing routes for it.

For now my structure looks like this

```
const controller = require('../../Controllers');
const libs = require('../../Lib');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', libs.util.isLoggedIn, libs.util.checkPermission('/user-dashboard', 'view'), (req, res, next) => {
controller.UserController.getDashboardDetail(req, res, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        next(error);
        return;
    }
    result.session = req.session;
    res.render('consume/user-dashboard', {
        coursearray: result,
        username: req.session.displayname
    });
}) 
});
```

As in this route `'/'`, i am requesting for user dashboard, so before providing this i validate user using 2 `middlewares` **Login** using `libs.util.isLoggedIn` function and permission using `libs.util.checkPermission` then my `controllers` provide the required data.

As we can after getting error free data i am rendering my `View` using `res.render`.

My problem is how can i use this same `API` when i only need that data which i am providing to `render` function to some mobile application?

I don't want to build another `API` for doing the same thing which i am already doing.

My `API`  should not care about whether page is built on `server` side or `client` side.

How should i modify my current `API` to achieve this?

Is there some mistake the structure i am using with my `routes`?

Comment: Don't render a view, but instead return JSON via `res.json`. Your frontend application and mobile apps will use the same API and will have to figure out how to render the JSON data in their respective views. I would also use JWT over typical browser sessions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you might choose to use, personally I'd recommend approach two for better separation of concerns and greater flexibility in the future. Though after understanding both you may decide that approach one is more suited for your needs if it's a smaller application which is less likely to change.

**Approach 1 - The Accepted header.**

The common convention is to check the `Accepted` header (or similar) to see which format it is requesting. If the client is asking for HTML then you can respond with a res.render response (such as a web browser), if they are requesting JSON, or XML then you can respond with those formats as required. You should be able to package this up as middleware for your routes and on your route definition pass through a template name which can be ignored if responding with JSON for example.

[See HTTP docs for more information on the Accepted header.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)

**Approach 2 - Unified business logic, with two thin applications**

An alternative (and a popular choice by most) is to build your business logic in some sort of "lib" module. Then build two thin web applications, one which serves HTML, and another which might live on the `/api` endpoint which serves just JSON.

So if a user requests `example.com/profile`, they'll get a HTML page back. If they request `example.com/api/profile` then they'll get back a JSON response. Both of these endpoints make a request to the `user` resource in your projects `lib` folder, but one then formats it for HTML, and the other for JSON. This is often the desired approach as HTML pages often pull from multiple resources to build up a page. For example, this stackoverflow page will show some user profile aspects, the question itself, the answers, "hot network questions", and "related questions". If you just requested a JSON representation, you'd expect to get just the question and subsequent answers.

Comment: Thanks, i would also like to go with Approach 2.